# Simulating a log normal distribution from a reported arithmetic mean/sd

Tags: normal-distribution, lognormal-distribution

I have a sample mean and sd of a variable X that I suspect is log-normally distributed. I calculated the mean and sd of the variable log(x) using the equations from the Wikipedia article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Notation). I then took these parameters for log(X) and simulated X in R using `rlnorm` or by exponentiating the data simulated with `rnorm`.

When I did this, I expected to be able to calculate the (artithmetic) mean and sd from these simulated data and recover my original starting values, but this didn't happen.

What am I missing?

```
# starting mean for X = 377, var = 46375

mu <- log(377 / sqrt(1 + (46375 / 377^2))) # mean of log(X)

var <- sqrt(log(1 + (46375 / 377^2))) # var of log(X)

# EDIT: THE PROBLEM IS THE sqrt() THERE. 

d1 <- exp(rnorm(1000, mu, sqrt(var)))
d2 <- rlnorm(1000, mu, sqrt(var))

data_frame(d = c(d1, d2), var = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 1000)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = d, fill = var)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.5)

mean(d1) # This isn't 377
mean(d2)
var(d1)  # This isn't 46375 
var(d2)
```

Comment: Gee, well, the mean logarithm is not the logarithm of the mean. It does not work that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work.

```
m = 377
v = 46375
sig2 = log(v + m^2) - 2*log(m)
mu = log(m) - sig2 / 2 

x = exp(rnorm(100000, mu, sqrt(sig2)))
mean(x)
# [1] 376.0851
var(x)
# [1] 46050.79
```